# Зачем указывать нулевой индекс в функции append()

Tags: python, bytearray

```
  b = bytearray('string', 'ascii')
  b.append(b'a'[0])#зачем этот нулевой индекс, если эта функция добавляет в конец объект
  print(b)
```

Comment: Вы нас спрашиваете про ваш же код? Напишите  его так, вам нравится.

Comment: `b'a'[0]` получает первый байт байтовой строки. В данном случае это число `97`. Потом это число куда-то добавляется (в конец).

Comment: Индекс относится к b'a', а не к append